# Bash find: changing matched name for use in -exec

Tags: bash, shell, find

I'm writing a deploy script, and I need to run a less compiler against all .less files in a directory. This is easy to do with the following find command:

```
find -name "*.less" -exec plessc {} {}.css \;
```

After running this command on a folder with a file named `main.less`, I'm left with a file named `main.less.css`, but I want it to be `main.css`.

I know I can easily strip the .less portion of the resulting files with this command:     `rename 's/\.less//' *.css` but I'm hoping to learn something new about using -exec.

Is it possible to modify the name of the file that matches while using it in the -exec parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your find command is using a couple of non standard GNU extensions:

- You do not state where to find, this is an error in POSIX but GNU find select the current directory in that case
- You use a non isolated {}, POSIX find doesn't expand it in that case.

Here is a one liner that should work with most find implementations and fix your double extension issue:

```
find . -name "*.less" -exec sh -c "plessc \$0 \$(dirname \$0)/\$(basename \$0 less)css" {} \;
```

On Solaris 10 and older, `sh -c` should be replaced by `ksh -c` if the PATH isn't POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to do it directly.  You can only use `{}` to directly insert the full filename.  However, in exec, you COULD put in other things like `awk`. Or you can redirect output to another program via pipes.

From the `find` `man` page:

```
   -exec command ;
          Execute command; true if 0 status is  returned.   All  following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an argument consisting of `;' is encountered.  The  string  `{}'
          is  replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere
          it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
          where  it  is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these
          constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to
          protect  them  from  expansion  by  the shell.  See the EXAMPLES
          section  for  examples  of  the  use  of  the -exec option.  The 
          specified command is run once for each matched file. The command 
          is executed in the starting directory.   There  are  unavoidable
          security  problems  surrounding  use  of  the -exec action;  you
          should use the -execdir option instead.
```